# Show that if $A_{0}(t)+A_{1}(t)W(t)=0$ for all $t$ with $A_{0}$ and $A_{1}$ differentiable in $t$ and $W(t)$ a Wiener process, then $A_{0}=A_{1}=0$

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation

I am learning the quadratic variation of stochastic process, and I am working on an exercise stating that

> If for all $t$, we have $$0=A_{0}(t)+A_{1}(t)W(t),$$ where $(A_{0}(t),\mathcal{F}_{t})$ and $(A_{1}(t),\mathcal{F}_{t})$ are processes with $C^{1}$ trajectories, and $W_{t}$ is a brownian motion with respect to $(\mathcal{F}_{t})$ then $A_{0}(t)=0$ and $A_{1}(t)=0$ for all $t$.

My current attempt:

We have $-A_{0}(t)=A_{1}(t)W(t)$, and set $g(t)=-A_{0}(t)$. Since $g(t)$ is $C^{1}$, it is of bounded variation, and thus it has zero quadratic variation.

Hence, $A_{1}(t)W(t)$ is of zero quadratic variation. I want to start from here to show that $A_{1}(t)W(t)$ is zero for all $t$, but I don't know what to do..

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\De{\Delta}$ $\newcommand\ep{\epsilon}$ $\newcommand\om{\omega}$  $\newcommand\Om{\Omega}$
Take any real $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$. For each natural $n$ and all $k=0,\dots,2^n$, let $t_k:=t_{k;n:a,b}:=a+k(b-a)/2^n$. Then 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}(\De_kW)^2\to b-a \tag{1}$$
(as $n\to\infty$) for almost all paths/realizations of $W$, where $\De_k B:=B(t_k)-B(t_{k-1})$ for any, possibly random function $B$; see e.g. [Theorem 2, formula (5)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec8.pdf). Without loss of generality, (1) holds for all paths/realizations of $W$. So, in what follows we may assume that the functions $W,A_0,A_1$ are non-random.

Suppose now that the function $A_1$ is nonzero. Since $A_1$ is $C^1$, it is continuous, and so, we may assume that that our $a$ and $b$ are such that $|A_1|\ge\ep$ on $[a,b]$ for some real $\ep>0$. From the condition $A_0+A_1W=0$ it follows that 
$$-\De_k A_0=A_1(t_k)\De_k W+W(t_{k-1})\De_k A_1,$$
whence
$$\ep^2(\De_k W)^2\le A_1(t_k)^2(\De_k W)^2
\le2(\De_k A_0)^2+2W(t_{k-1})^2(\De_k A_1)^2.$$
Since $A_0,A_1$ are in $C^1$ and $W$ is continuous, we have 
$$(\De_k A_0)^2+(\De_k A_1)^2\le M(\De t_k)^2\quad\text{and}\quad W(t_{k-1})^2\le M$$
for some real $M>0$ and all $k=0,\dots,n$, where $\De t_k:=t_k-t_{k-1}=(b-a)/2^n$. So,
$$\ep^2\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}(\De_k W)^2
\le2M\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}(\De t_k)^2+2M^2\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}(\De t_k)^2.$$
Letting now $n\to\infty$, we get $\ep^2(b-a)\le0$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $A_1=0$ and hence $A_0=-A_1W=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $t>0$. On the event $\{A_1(t)\not=0\}$ you have a maximal random open interval $I(t)$ containing $t$ on which $A_1$ doesn't vanish. For  $s\in I(t)$ you have $W(s) =-A_0(s)/A_1(s)$. As this ratio is $C^1$ on $I(t)$, while $W$ is nowhere differentiable (or even, because $W$ has strictly positive quadratic variation) almost surely, you have a contradiction. There $P(A_1(t) =0)=1$ for each $t$. Because $A_1$ is continuous, $P(A_1(t)=0,\forall t)=1$. This leaves $0=A_0(t)$ for all $t$ (a.s.).

Alternatively, once you realize that $A_1(t)W(t)$ has zero quadratic variation, Ito's formula yields 
$$
\int_0^t A_1(s)\,dW(s) = A_1(t)W(t)-\int_0^t W(s)A'_1(s)\,ds.
$$
The right side has zero quadratic variation, hence so does the left. But the quadratic variation of the (local martingale on the) left side is
$$
\int_0^t A_1(s)^2\,ds.
$$
As this vanishes, you have, upon differentiating, that $A_1(t)^2=0$ for all $t$, a.s.